# Fonts look strange in firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts

I have just moved from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04 (with Firefox 11), and the fonts in some of my favorite sites (especially Hebrew sites) look strange.

I looked at the CSS and saw such fonts such as "David", "Arial", etc. Apparently these fonts are not installed on my Firefox. How do I install them?

Comment: There is a [very old bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/23267), with the fix long overdue. Please leave a comment if you are affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arial font is get installed by `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and the David font is [available in `culmus` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/culmus/filelist).

Open a terminal and do this command to get them

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer culmus
```

Or using Software center:

[image: Install ttf-mscorefonts via the software center]

[image: Install culmus via the software center]

If you want to install only the David font (culmus package includes some other fonts too), you can download that font from the link below

[Download link for David font only](http://fontzone.net/font-details/David/)

Download it and copy the font file in the `.fonts` directory in your home. This directory is hidden by default. Use `Ctrl` + `H` to reveal the hidden files and folders.
If the directory does not exists already, create one with name *.fonts* and copy the file in that directory.

**Note:** You have to accept the EULA when installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for navigation in the terminal.

[Reference]

1. Arial is installed by ttf-mscorefonts-installer as described in the [package's description](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ttf-mscorefonts-installer)
2. David font is in the culmus package as described by the [package's file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/culmus/filelist)

Comment: ‎Thanks for the detailed answer. Note that in culmus, the font name is "David CLM" and not "David".

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package. (Hint: Use the tab key to accept the EULA)

Incidentally, it's also part of the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` bundle, so that if you need java and multimedia codecs, install that instead.

You might also be interested in `culmus` and `culmus-fancy`.

Last, but not least, the installed fonts will be available for all, not just Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Search for "microsoft core fonts"
3. Install package "Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts"

OR, in run this command in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Either way, you will be asked to accept the EULA, which you have to say "Yes" if you want the fonts installed.

Finally, you may have to close Firefox and open it again. If didn't work, try logging-out-and-loggin-in.

Comment: I know, Arial font is in the package (more correctly, the package install it). But is David font is not installed by `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about font/typeface "David", but I'm almost sure it's not installed in Windows by default. You can get "font-config" to provide another font instead of that one though. More info: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **"Ubuntu Restricted Extras"**

It is available from the Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: Installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package for a font problem is I think not a good idea. He can easily install the small one (ttf-mscorefonts-installer)