# Firefox fonts changed after install ttf-mscorefonts

Tags: firefox, fonts, xfce, pipelight

My question is probably simple but I can't find a way to revert it to the previous state.

After installing `mscorecofonts` (which was installed during `pipelight` installation) my fonts in Firefox went crazy and it is ugly as hell now.

Can anyone advise how to reset to the "default" font setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience `ttf-mscorefonts` installs *broken* MS fonts. If I had such an issue as you report, I would go to `Firefox > Edit > Prefs > Content > Fonts > Advanced` and select there either the `Deja Vu` or the `Liberation` font families, both designed for on-screen display.

This should deal with the crazy fonts. If it still doesn't work, you may also experiment with different sizes in that dialogue.

Also see:

- [font looks bad in Browsers (Firefox and Chrome)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177564/font-looks-bad-in-browsers-firefox-and-chrome?lq=1)
- [Can I override fonts installed by ttf-mscorefonts-installer, prefer Liberation fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210590/can-i-override-fonts-installed-by-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-prefer-liberation-f?rq=1)
- [Fonts look strange in firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166965/fonts-look-strange-in-firefox?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, especially second link for some websites override that settings. still not perfect - can't find working settings for most fonts replaced by mscorefonts, but i know now where to look

Comment: Great. Please also consider upvoting the answer (see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8373/whats-wrong-ask-ubuntu-low-voter-count ).

Comment: tried it already, but i don't have a required reputation to upvote your comment...

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I thought you could do that on your own questions.