# Fonts don't show as expected in firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, firefox, fonts, unicode, hebrew

**Problem description:**

I have `firefox (Hebrew) 4.0` installed on `Ubuntu 16.04` and it shows *Hebrew fonts* like so (the rectangles with Unicode addresses should be Hebrew letters):

[image: haifa.muni.il]

### Can you suggest where the problem lies, and optionally, how to solve it?

**Background:**

I need to use an older `firefox,` because [filling Hebrew forms online](https://www.haifa.muni.il/Services/PSC/Arnona/pages/arnona-forms.aspx) is only supported with `firefox` up to *version 4.*

These are the steps I took to install the `Hebrew firefox:`

```
wget https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/4.0/linux-x86_64/he/firefox-4.0.tar.bz2
tar xvf firefox-4.0.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox/ /opt/firefox4he
sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox4us
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox4he/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

**Edit 1:**

Following @Nisheet suggestion, I did `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer culmus`

Now Hebrew is not seen at all:

[image: with culmus]

Comment: Try and see if this helps.

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer culmus`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fonts look strange in firefox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166965/fonts-look-strange-in-firefox)

Comment: See `Edit 1,` @Nisheet.

Comment: Does this work? I am not really sure, since the firefox you are using is a pretty old version.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hebrew-il-language-pack/

Comment: Please keep in mind that Firefox 4 is extremely vulnerable to exploits in its rendering engine and JavaScript parser.

Comment: Install the `fonts-sil-ezra` package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Nonny but there's not much I can no about it, as it's only FF 3.8, 3.9 and 4.0 to choose from.

Comment: My system informs me `fonts-sil-ezra is already the newest version (2.51-8),` @Gunnar.

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust Firefox's fonts settings (_Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Fonts & Colors_).

Comment: @boardrider Yeah, sorry I couldn't be of any real help. I just thought I'd throw that out there.

Comment: You don't need an ancient Firefox version to display the fonts correctly. Could you please try the Firefox version that comes with Ubuntu? It displays the Hebrew text fine, but when I try to access the online forms it asks me to install some "browser toolbar extension" and the link to the add-on file returns a web site with an "unsupported operation" message. (The additional fuck-up being, that the web server sends response code 200 ("OK") instead of one of the error codes (400–599) for a resource that cannot be found.)